# node.js socket.io pass io to export module

Tags: node.js, socket.io

i'm trying to set up a very simple websocket server that will notify a webpage when API calls are being made.

This code works with `io.emit('event', 'hejhej');`

```
   module.exports = function(app, io) {
        var router = express.Router();
        require('../modules/socket-handeler.js')(io);

        router.route('/getOperatingInformation')
            .get(function(req, res) {
                dal.getOperatingInformationEntries(function (responsedata) {
                    //notifyNewOperatingInformation();
                    io.emit('event', 'hejhej');
                    res.json(responsedata);
                });
            });
```

However i would like to have all emits in a module, socket-handeler.js:

```
module.exports = function (io) {
    var module = {};

    module.notifyNewOperatingInformation = function() {
        io.emit('event', 'hejhej');
    }

    return module;
}
```

However `notifyNewOperatingInformation();` is not working, no message it sent to client.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: you are not initalizing the module variable here ```var iomod = require('../modules/socket-handeler.js')(io); iomod.notifyNewOperatingInformation();```